# How can see different Record-view per Profiles Users?

Tags: list-view

[image]

I want to view control using by Profiles, but has no ideas currently.

Does anyone knows best option for this situation?

Regards, CKJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot control the record access using profiles we can only set read, create, edit, delete access for the object but not for records.

We have to define the OWD as private and the give the access to the records based on sharing rules.

As you need profile wise sharing you can create a public group  and add the users under that profile to that public groups .

We can also create [restriction rule](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_restriction_rule_create.htm&type=5)s so the  data that the user has access to via org-wide defaults, sharing rules, and other sharing mechanisms is filtered by the record criteria that you specify.